# Replacing DOM elements that have no attributes

Tags: javascript, html, dom

The institution I work for uses an application that has an awful software bug causing useless `<code>span</code>` tags to appear next to "misspelled" words in iframes.

For instance, HTML that should look like this:

```
<span class="myClass">Hello! My name is Tabitha.</span>
```

...might look like this instead:

```
<span class="myClass">Hello! My name is <span><span><span><span><span>Tabitha.</span></span></span></span></span></span>
```

My band-aid solution, while we wait for a fix from the application developer, has been to add a script that finds all attribute-less `span` tags and replaces them with a new `<code>textNode</code>`. This works because these extra tags are **always** the direct parent of the `<code>textNode</code>` containing the misspelled word (or another extra `span` element). Any formatting or inline styling would occur outside that scope and would thus be unaffected.

But, something tells me there's got to be a better way to do it. Any thoughts?

```
function fixSpan(iframe) {        
    var doc = iframe.contentDocument;
    var spans = doc.getElementsByTagName('span'); //find all <span> elements
    for (var i = 0; i < spans.length; i++) {
        var span = spans[i];            
        var tag = span.outerHTML.slice(0,6);
        if (tag === '<span>') { //if the span has no attributes
            //replace it with a new textNode containing its textContent
            console.log('FOUND: <span>' + span.textContent + '</span>');
            span.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(span.textContent), span);                
        }
    }

    if (doc.documentElement.innerHTML.includes('<span>')) {
        //if any attribute-less tags remain, run the method again
        console.log('Fix not complete, re-running...');
        fixSpan(iframe);
    } else {
        console.log('Fix complete.');
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the harm in leaving the extra tags there? What is the benefit of doing the cleanup?

Answer (score 1):

Some thoughts about your code:

1) You work with the serialized form of the HTML, i.e. with `innerHTML` and `outerHTML`. In some (rare) occurrences, it may be acceptable to do so, but most of the time working with the provided API is cleaner. I don't think that the serialized representation is guaranteed to be the same across user agents (attribute ordering, legacy uppercasing of HTML...) - plus what if some inline script declares some '`<span>`' text... like yours?

2) Re-running the method is a bit dubious, you should be able to remove all `spans` in a single pass. In your case, the DOM collection is live, so each time you replace a `span` element, the current index must be shifted back. In itself, manually updating the index of a loop is a bad practice, but Javascript has limited iteration mechanisms, so you have to live with it. It's actually not that unusual in DOM manipulation.

3) Removing the `spans` without attributes is well and good, but even an empty span may be styled, as part of another selector (e.g. `.foo > span`). Your fix may bring new problems.

4) Comments should not repeat the code, but bring enlightenment to the reader. Indicating "find all `<span>` elements" aside a `getElementsByTagName` is probably unneeded. Indicating why you shift a loop index, if you decide to do it, is necessary.

```
function fixSpan(doc) {
    var spans = doc.getElementsByTagName("span");
    for (var index = 0; index < spans.length; index++) {
        var span = spans[index];
        if (span.attributes.length == 0) {
            span.parentNode.replaceChild(document.createTextNode(span.textContent), span);
            index--; // Tree is live; removing one span requires shifting the index.
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Regarding your second point: use [`document.querySelectorAll()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelectorAll) which returns a non-live NodeList

Comment: @Andreas Thanks for the pointer. I've never used this method, but it looks interesting.